# ffmpeg says that file doesn't exist, but it actually exists

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, nestjs

Trying to extract audio from video so in my NestJS controller i used `ffmpeg` to solve it, but it says me that file does not exist
This is my handler in controller:

```js
try {
    let process = new ffmpeg("/uploads/0.777341078548575.mp4")
    process.then(function (video) {
        video.fnExtractSoundToMP3(
            '/uploads/audio/test/007',
            function (error, file) {if (!error) console.log('Audio file: ' + file)}
        )
    }, function (err) {
           console.log('Error: ' + err)
    })
} catch (e) {
    console.log("CATCHED ERROR", e)
}
```

And this is what `ffmpeg` says me
`CATCHED ERROR { code: 103, msg: 'The input file does not exist' }`
But i used right path, so cant get where the problem is, on the picture you can see where my video file is store
[image]

I tried different paths: `../../uploads/0.777341078548575.MP4`, `/uploads/0.777341078548575.MP4`, `../../uploads/0.777341078548575.mp4`, `/uploads/0.777341078548575.mp4` and also all these paths without `.mp4` or `.MP4`

Comment: Are you really sure the path is correct? `/uploads` would be in the root of your filesystem, next to `/bin`, `/home`, etc. `./uploads` would be in the current working directory (which may or may not be the same directory as the script).

Comment: @RickN added picture to see my path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `.ts` file is in `transcribation/transcribation.controller.ts` but the file you are accessing is not in the same folder. It's actually 1 level up.

Make sure you are going 1 level up to access the videos

```
let process = new ffmpeg("../uploads/0.1831579264771055.mp4")
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is
Reinstall ffmpeg
Or using Sudo command

Comment: this didnt helped (